Create a single node mysql cluster with testcontainers in golang for testing
What I usually do, is login to my server with mysqlsh and then
dba.checkInstanceConfiguration()
dba.createCluster("mycluster")

But now I need to create a single node cluster inside a testcontainer as part of an End2End-Test.
How do I accomplish this with testcontainers-go?
Currently I am trying to build the container like:
    testExec := testcontainers.NewRawCommand([]string{`echo "dba.configureInstance();dba.createCluster(\"mycluster\") | mysqlsh -ppassword -uroot`})
    mysqlContainer, err := mysql.RunContainer(ctx,
        testcontainers.WithImage(mysqlImageVersion),
        mysql.WithUsername("root"),
        mysql.WithPassword("password"),
        mysql.WithDatabase("mysql"),
        testcontainers.WithAfterReadyCommand(testExec),
        mysql.WithConfigFile(filepath.Join("test", "test.cnf")),
    )


The contents of the config file from "WithConfigFile":
[mysqld]


skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
secure-file-priv=/var/lib/mysql-files
user=mysql

server_id                               = 12345678
binlog_transaction_dependency_tracking  = WRITESET
gtid_mode                           = ON
enforce_gtid_consistency            = ON


pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
[client]
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock


But this doesn't seem to work.
When I run a command to check for the primary (I got this cmd from here)
SELECT member_host FROM performance_schema.global_status JOIN performance_schema.replication_group_members WHERE variable_name = 'group_replication_primary_member' AND member_id=variable_value
I am getting an empty result. I would expect the name of the primary instance.
